# How to run a Dynamic mongo query in Java

Tags: java, mongodb-query

I am trying to run a dynamic mongodb query in my Java application. But I am getting `NoClassDefFound` error. What am I doing wrong?

```
DB mongoDB = mongoclient.getDB("test");

String query = "db.test.find({'address':'Sydney'})";
MongoQuery mongoQuery = new MongoQueryParser().parse(query, new 
HashMap());

BasicDBList results = mongoQuery.execute(mongoDB);
System.out.println(results.size());
```

I except the result to be:

```
{ "_id" : "106", "full_name" : "Susan Dixit", "address" : "Sydney" }
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
com.mongodb.casbah.MongoDB
at com.ee.dynamicmongoquery.MongoQuery.execute(MongoQuery.scala:13)
at mongodata.main(mongodata.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.casbah.MongoDB.
```

Comment: Make sure you have imported the right library!

Comment: Not enough information to solve this. This heavily depends on your setup, both build wise and IDE wise. Make sure you got Mongo DB on your build dependencies (in the right version) then try to use your build tool in a clean setup to build it (e.g. `./gradlew clean build`) and then run it. If it compiles but you can't run it for instance then the build is wrong and it is missing on your classpath. You can also try to rebuild from fresh in your IDE or clean projects, etc. but what to do depends on the IDE.

Comment: This problem is not with your code. Its either with how you are building the jar or how you are running it.

Comment: I am running it on Eclipse Neon, and I am using 1.mongo-java driver jar  2. mongo shell like query jar  3.bson jar

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the db.eval command. For example:

```
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

Bson command = new Document("eval", "db.test.find({\"address\":\"Sydney\"})");
Document result = database.runCommand(command);
```

Alternatively, you can also pass just the filter as a string in case that is what you want to provide dynamically. Example:

```
DBCollection collection = database.getCollection("test");

BasicDBObject query = BasicDBObject.parse("{\"address\":\"Sydney\"}");

FindIterable<Document> dumps = collection.find(query);
```