# Create a dynamic Mongo query in Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm migrating MongoDB with Hibernate OGM & ORM to 'pure' Java MongoDB (org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.4.0.

As: "Hibernate OGM is not going to work with ORM 5.5 (the latest version requires ORM 5.3)".

[How to use Hibernate ORM 5.5.x.Final with Jakarta 9 on wildfly-preview-25.0.0.Final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69824241/how-to-use-hibernate-orm-5-5-x-final-with-jakarta-9-on-wildfly-preview-25-0-0-fi)

I now want to create a 'dynamic' version say x -> 99 (FindIterable Document). As I did similar with Hibernate OGM & ORM:

```
if (MotorcycleController.motorcycleManufacturers.length > MotorcyclesEJB.ZERO) {
    stringBuilderSQL.append(WHERE);
    stringBuilderSQL.append(OPEN_BRACKET);

    for (int x = MotorcyclesEJB.ZERO; x < MotorcycleController.motorcycleManufacturers.length; x++) {
        stringBuilderSQL.append(MotorcyclesEJB.MANUFACTURER);
        stringBuilderSQL.append(MotorcyclesEJB.EQUALS);
        stringBuilderSQL.append(MotorcyclesEJB.SINGLE_QUOTE);
        stringBuilderSQL.append(MotorcycleController.motorcycleManufacturers[x]);
        stringBuilderSQL.append(MotorcyclesEJB.SINGLE_QUOTE);

        if ((x + ONE) < MotorcycleController.motorcycleManufacturers.length) {
            stringBuilderSQL.append(MotorcyclesEJB.OR);
        }
    
        stringBuilderSQL.append(CLOSE_BRACKET);
    }
}
```

I can create (a static) multiple persion of MongoDB 'Collection' using:

```
FindIterable<Document> motorcycleApriliaMotoGuzzi = mongoCollectionMotorcycleManufacturer.find(or(eq("manufacturer", "Aprilia"), eq("manufacturer", "Moto Guzzi")));
```

Which can show results (example of one):

```
INFO  [com.gostophandle.ejb.MongoDBEJB] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 97) >>>>> motorcycleApriliaMotoGuzzi = Document{{_id=61d70d6a8c9e88075702af3e, manufacturer=Aprilia, model=RS 660, modelType=E5, typesOf=Sport, dateProductionStarted=Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2021, dateProductionEnded=Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2021, engine=Document{{type=Four-Stroke, displacement=659.0, cylinder=2.0, capacityUnit=cc, carburation=, bore=0.0, boreMeasurement=mm, stroke=0.0, strokeMeasurement=mm, distribution=, maxiumPowerHp=0.0, maxiumPowerKilowatt=0.0, maxiumPowerRpm=0.0, maximumTorque=0.0, maximumTorqueUnit=Nm, maximumTorqueRpm=0.0}}, performance=Document{{topSpeedMph=105.0, topSpeedKph=0.0, accelleration30Mph=0.0, accelleration60Mph=0.0, accelleration100Mph=0.0, accelleration30Kph=0.0, accelleration60Kph=0.0, accelleration100Kph=0.0}}, dimensionsWeights=Document{{batteryCapacity=, casterAngleDegrees=0.0, dimensionsL=0.0, dimensionsW=0.0, dimensionsH=0.0, frameType=, fuelTankCapacityLitres=0.0, fuelConsumption=0.0, groundClearance=0.0, kerbWeight=0.0, seatHeight=0.0, trail=0.0, wheelbase=0.0}}, chassisBrakesSuspensionWheels=Document{{frame=1, swingarm=2, absSystem=3, frontBrakes=4, rearBrakes=5, frontSuspension=6, rearSuspension=7, tyresFront=8, tyresRear=9, frontTyre=10, rearTyre=11, frontWheel=12, rearWheel=13, instrumentDisplayFunctions=14}}, transmission=Document{{clutch=1, clutchOperation=2, finalDrive=3, gearbox=4, transmissionType=5, primaryReduction=0.0, gearRatios1st=0.0, greaRatios2nd=0.0, gearRatios3rd=0.0, gearRatios4th=0.0, gearRatios5th=0.0, gearRatios6th=0.0}}, instruments=Document{{headlights=1, socket=2, ignitionSystem=3, instruments=4, tailLight=5, usbSocket=6}}, electrics=Document{{}}, colours=[Document{{colour=Acid Gold}}, Document{{colour=Lava Red}}, Document{{colour=Apex Black}}], accessories=[], image=Document{{file=/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/GoStopHandle/images, url=/Aprilia/2021/, png=ap6115200ebm03-01-m.webp, dimensionsWidth=1500, dimensionsHeight=1000}}}}
```

I can't get it to create a dynamic version using 'find', 'or' & 'eq' etc.

Any suggestions? TIA.

Comment: Your original code looks like it is prone to SQL injection.

Comment: There is some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57488543/102937), although that `eval` call gives me pause.  The second method described in the answer there might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `Filters` methods for constructing the Bson for OR:

```
Filters.or(Bson...)
Filters.or(Iterable<Bson>)
```

Using the latter, you can construct `Bson` for each of your conditions that you want to OR together, collect them in a List, and then pass that list to that method to construct the `Bson` for the OR.  I guess this is really an IN operation because these are all the same field but for demonstration purposes:

```
public Bson or(String field, List<String> values) {
  return Filters.or(
      values.stream()
        .map(v -> Filters.eq(field, v))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@vsfDawg - Perfect

```
 List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
 stringList.add("Aprilia");
 stringList.add("Moto Guzzi");

 Bson bson = or("manufacturer", stringList);

 MongoCursor<Document> cursor = mongoCollectionMotorcycles.find(or("manufacturer", stringList)).iterator();;
 try {
     while (cursor.hasNext()) {
         LOGGER.info(">>>>> 6.4 motorcycleApriliaMotoGuzzi = {}", cursor.next());
     }
 } finally {
     cursor.close();
 }

public Bson or(String field, List<String> values) {
    return Filters.or(
        values.stream()
           .map(v -> Filters.eq(field, v))
           .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

Displays data:

```
INFO  [com.gostophandle.ejb.MotorcyclesEJB] (default task-1) >>>>> 6.4 motorcycleApriliaMotoGuzzi = Document{{_id=61d70d6a8c9e88075702af3e, manufacturer=Aprilia, model=RS 660, modelType=E5, typesOf=Sport, dateProductionStarted=Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2021, dateProductionEnded=Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2021, engine=Document{{type=Four-Stroke, displacement=659.0, cylinder=2.0, capacityUnit=cc, carburation=, bore=0.0, boreMeasurement=mm, stroke=0.0, strokeMeasurement=mm, distribution=, maxiumPowerHp=0.0, maxiumPowerKilowatt=0.0, maxiumPowerRpm=0.0, maximumTorque=0.0, maximumTorqueUnit=Nm, maximumTorqueRpm=0.0}}, performance=Document{{topSpeedMph=105.0, topSpeedKph=0.0, accelleration30Mph=0.0, accelleration60Mph=0.0, accelleration100Mph=0.0, accelleration30Kph=0.0, accelleration60Kph=0.0, accelleration100Kph=0.0}}, dimensionsWeights=Document{{batteryCapacity=, casterAngleDegrees=0.0, dimensionsL=0.0, dimensionsW=0.0, dimensionsH=0.0, frameType=, fuelTankCapacityLitres=0.0, fuelConsumption=0.0, groundClearance=0.0, kerbWeight=0.0, seatHeight=0.0, trail=0.0, wheelbase=0.0}}, chassisBrakesSuspensionWheels=Document{{frame=1, swingarm=2, absSystem=3, frontBrakes=4, rearBrakes=5, frontSuspension=6, rearSuspension=7, tyresFront=8, tyresRear=9, frontTyre=10, rearTyre=11, frontWheel=12, rearWheel=13, instrumentDisplayFunctions=14}}, transmission=Document{{clutch=1, clutchOperation=2, finalDrive=3, gearbox=4, transmissionType=5, primaryReduction=0.0, gearRatios1st=0.0, greaRatios2nd=0.0, gearRatios3rd=0.0, gearRatios4th=0.0, gearRatios5th=0.0, gearRatios6th=0.0}}, instruments=Document{{headlights=1, socket=2, ignitionSystem=3, instruments=4, tailLight=5, usbSocket=6}}, electrics=Document{{}}, colours=[Document{{colour=Acid Gold}}, Document{{colour=Lava Red}}, Document{{colour=Apex Black}}], accessories=[], image=Document{{file=/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/GoStopHandle/images, url=/Aprilia/2021/, png=ap6115200ebm03-01-m.webp, dimensionsWidth=1500, dimensionsHeight=1000}}}}
12:42:59,335 INFO  [com.gostophandle.ejb.MotorcyclesEJB] (default task-1) >>>>> 6.4 motorcycleApriliaMotoGuzzi = Document{{_id=61d70d6a8c9e88075702af58, manufacturer=Moto Guzzi, model=Le Mans, modelType=I, typesOf=Sport, dateProductionStarted=Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1976, dateProductionEnded=Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 1977, engine=Document{{type=Four-Stroke, displacement=850.0, cylinder=2.0, capacityUnit=cc, carburation=null, bore=80.0, boreMeasurement=mm, stroke=74.0, strokeMeasurement=mm, distribution=null, maxiumPowerHp=85.0, maxiumPowerKilowatt=38.0, maxiumPowerRpm=6200.0, maximumTorque=60.0, maximumTorqueUnit=Nm, maximumTorqueRpm=4900.0}}, electrics=Document{{}}, colours=[Document{{colour=Red}}, Document{{colour=Silver Blue}}], accessories=[Document{{productNumber=MG0123456789, productName=Product 1}}, Document{{productNumber=MG0123456789, productName=Product 2}}], image=Document{{file=/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/GoStopHandle/images, url=/MotoGuzzi/1976/, png=motorcycle.png, dimensionsWidth=900, dimensionsHeight=440}}}}
```